# How to retrieve data using a "not" as statement?

Tags: php, mysql

i´ve been working in a quiz script.
Questions are selected by a rand() query.

```
        table question
    +--------------------------------+
    |   question_id   |   question   |
    |         1       |     test?    |
    |         2       |     test 2?  |
    |--------------------------------+
```

If the user answers the question 1, it will be saved here:

```
        table answered

    id  |  user_id  | q_answered |  
    6   |    4      |      1     |
    -----------------------------+
```

I would like to users only gets questions unanswered by him. Only question_id not in q_answered.
like:
"selected * from questions where questions_id =! from table_answered(q_answered)"

How would be the PHP/Mysql query?

Comment: *"Only question_id ***`not in`*** q_answered."* - you basically answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answered WHERE user_id = ?)
```

This would get all questions that have not been answered by the given user (`?` is a bound parameter in PHP).

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2c9f/1).